# updatepanel still trigger full page postback when using master page

Tags: asp.net

Very strange behavior, I've created a master page by Visiostudio 2013 web express, and one page using that master page, everything by default, only added script manage to the master page.

Now when I input the following code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" />                
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this works in master page, no full page postback occurred
however, if I put this code into client page, everytime I type something into the textbox, it triggers the full page postback
and I noticed that if I take out the ClientIDMode="Static", no more full page postback cursors

I tried .net framework 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2, tried onto two different server, same symptom, am I missing anything?

Comment: did you add this tag <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>

Comment: although, may I ask that why the updatepanel in master page doesn't require the trigger? also, how do I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: just click on upper arrow...if you found useful..

Comment: Just read this doc you can understand how it is working https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read this doc you can understand how it is working https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: although still feel confusion on this behavior, but will mark this as an answer.  According to the doc, "By default, any postback control inside an UpdatePanel control causes an asynchronous postback and refreshes the panel's content.", therefore, I suppose my textbox control shouldn't need trigger since it's inside the updatepanel, but adding the trigger do solve my problem, any more info are always welcome

Answer (score 0):

alright, after hours debugging, i've finally found the real cause, is actually the ajaxcontroltoolkit causing the weird updatepanel behavior, after removing the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll from the bin folder, everything backs to normal